# What causes a notice to be added without a bounty starting?

Tags: support, post-notices

Looking at a revision history, I noticed something strange. A notice seems to have been added without starting a bounty, then removed by a moderator two days later (click image for link):

[image]

**What causes this sort of thing with a notice appearing without a bounty?**

Comment: If it helps, there was a user who left SE. He used his association bonus on _all_ the sites to give away instead of offering bounty genuinely to questions and answers. Hence they were cancelled by an employee.

Comment: @NogShine you aren't allowed to just give away a bunch of reputation?

Comment: I think no. Rep should be awarded to ones which deserve. You can't just give away for a random answer without knowing the topic at all. The user offered bounty on all the websites based on high score (around 170 when they left). That is not the way to offer bounties.

Answer (score 5):

Starting a bounty involves two changes: adding the bounty itself, and adding the notice.  There are two corresponding history entries at the end of the bounty.
You can see that with an earlier bounty on the question you linked.

In the case of the notices you're asking about, the bounty was cancelled and refunded.  You can deduce this from the fact that the notice was removed by neither the bounty-giver nor the Community user but, rather, by a moderator or employee.  When a bounty is cancelled it's actually undone; it's as if the bounty action never existed.  You can see this in the bounty-giver's [bounty history](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2128/farewell-stack-exchange?tab=bounties&sort=offered), which shows no offered bounties.

The notices, however, remain in the question history.